# Cannot scroll to element if position absolute and overflow-x hidden specified

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I have animated `ng-view`. I'm using slideup animation, which requires absolute position of elements and also `overflow-x: hidden` to clip the content. In one sub-page I have to use `scrollTo` element functionality, but it doesn't work if **both** 2 values are specified.
Here is a main `ng-view` class which is required for correct animations

```
.wrapper {
    position: absolute !important; 
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
```

And structure:

```
<div class="wrapper ng-view-div">
 <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href du-smooth-scroll="section-1" du-scrollspy>Section 1</a></li>
            <li><a href du-smooth-scroll="section-2" du-scrollspy>Section 2</a></li>
            <li><a href du-smooth-scroll="section-3" du-scrollspy>Section 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

<section id="section-1" style="background-color: red">
  C
</section>
<section id="section-2"  style="background-color: blue">
  C
</section>
<section id="section-3"  style="background-color: green">
  C
</section>
</div>
```

I prepared [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/ILcnMV3C7xzdiiI4dPsl?p=preview) to easily show how it looks like for now. Is there any other way to achieve scroll working but with this two values ?

Comment: This seems an angularjs bug. The native `.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'})` works properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, height:100% in the wrapper CSS class creates an issue. Please use the wrapper CSS class below.

```
.wrapper {
    position: absolute !important; 
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: It's really working, hmm do you know why this height property causes the problem ? Thank you